# Remove indexes from a datatable in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, indexing, datatable

I'm using C# to copy a SQL Server table into a DataTable.

How do I delete/remove indexes that are transferred to the DataTable?

Comment: Why do you wish to remove the indexes? It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy an SQL table to a Datatable via a SQLAdapter or using a Datareader it doesn't copy indexes.

Datatables don't have indexes (like Clustered and Non-Clustered).

Comment: Thanks, your comments made me realize that the SQL Server table index was transferred to the datatable as a Constraint.

Comment: Oh OK I see, we call those Relationships and we refer to them as  DataTables in a DataSet.